# Неправильный запрос или не тот ход мыслей

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, sql

Подскажите принцип реализации такой вот задачи.

Имеется форма с **DBGrid1**. При клике по строке открывается другая вкладка с другим **DBGrid2**, где выводятся данные согласно id кликнутой строки в первом **DBGrid1**. Дак вот, при изменении данных в **DBGrid2** изменяется информация так же и в **DBGrid1**.

```
   try
   isxSql:=DM.Query_zakaz.SQL.Text;
   DM.Query_zakaz.SQL.Clear;
   DM.Query_zakaz.SQL.Add('UPDATE Заказы SET Сс_Предв="'+t1+'" WHERE ID='+inttostr(DM.id));
   DM.Query_zakaz.ExecSQL;
   DM.Query_zakaz.SQL.Clear;
   DM.Query_zakaz.SQL.Add(isxSql);
   DM.Query_zakaz.Active:=true;

   except
     on e:Exception do
   end;
```

Проблема в том, что **DM.Query_zakaz** обновляется весь и в **DBGrid2** загружаются данные самой первой строки из **DBGrid1**.

Например, я выбрал в **DBGrid1** запись №5. Открылась таблица с данными согласно записи №5. При редактировании записи в этой таблице данный запрос подставляет все значения согласно записи №1 и сохраняет их. Как будто я открывал запись №1, а не №5.

Чувствую, в этой конструкции проблема (истина где-то рядом), что только не перепробовал, всё бесполезно. Нужно, чтобы данные обновились в 1-й таблице, но не перезагружали бы мне все таблицы, открытые в данный момент для работы.

Работаю с базой через ADOQuery, не через ADOTable!

Answer (score 1):

Приведенный исходник вообще далек от текстового описания задачи
deterok, при чем тут MVC?

Задача решается реализацией механизма Master/Detail Когда 2 датасета связывают между собой по курсору через ключевые поля. Учите матчасть.
Вот первое, что попалось под руку
http://cadhouse.narod.ru/articles/ado_master_detail/ado_master_detail.htm

Answer (score 1):

Что касается проблемы:

Я предполагаю что у Вас передается неправильный DM.id, а именно берется ИД первой записи, вот данная запись и обновляется. Все может быть даже хуже если вы используете тот же набор данных для первого грида, тогда у вас берется ID с второй таблицы, а обновляются данные с первой.

Небольшие рекомендации:

- Пустой блок try except. Если вы не в режиме отладки - тогда все ошибки, которые возникли в блоке  try except будут подавляться. Как вариант можно записывать ошибки в лог (см. пример ниже) или выводить свое уведомление. В дальнейшем избавит от проблем и вопроса - почему же оно не работает.

Пример:

```
try
except
    on E: Exception do
      WriteLog(E.Message);
end;
```

- Использование параметров для выполнения запросов. (попробуйте в переменную записать значение в котором есть апостроф)

Пример:

```
Query.SQL.Text := 'UPDATE TableName Set Value = :p1 WHERE id = :id';
Query.ParamByName('p1').Value := Param1Value;
Query.ParamByName('id').Value := ParamIDValue;
Query.ExecSQL;
```

- Не используйте один объект ADOQuery для выборки данных и обновления данных. Создайте динамически отдельный. Только не забудьте в таком случае обновить ADOQuery после обновления данных ;-)

Уже не первый раз описываю рекомендации, похоже нужно будет все оформить в виде  заметок у себя в [блоге](http://mirsovetov.net/blog) и давать ссылку.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, что Grid'ы связаны между собой одним общим источником данных?

В общем, я не знаю, как ваше волшебное древнее ADO должно работать, но предполагаю, что у вас проблемы с подразделением на Модель/Представление. Надо попробовать сделать раздельные "источники данных". Хотя я повторюсь, по вашему участку кода ничерта не поймешь...